# Alinear texto a la derecha de un ícono HTML5/CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Les planteo la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que el texto del contendor DIV se ubique a la derecha del ícono de información, para que el texto no quede desaliñado. Comento que el ícono es una propiedad de Font Awesome Icons con HTML, he intentado con las propiedades 'float' de CSS, text-align, etc., pero no funciona. ¿Podría ser una incompatibilidad con Font Awesome Icons?, espero una solución y gracias.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.0/js/all.js"></script>

<div style="padding:3px;position:relative;border-radius:10px;background:linear-gradient(to right, #44d9e6, #0978ef)">
  <div style="background:#fff;padding:1rem;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:#0978ef"></i>
    Contáctanos a través de la vía correspondiente en caso de tener alguna duda, inconveniente o sugerencia.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Un mínimo de código que nos ayudara a reproducir tu escenario haría mas fácil que los demás puedan tratar de responderte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que crear un nuevo `div` y añadirle dentro los dos elementos (icono y texto). Una vez hecho eso, añadiendo el `css`  `display: flex` sobre el nuevo `div` que has creado se te ordenan los elementos de dentro de izquierda a derecha.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="width:30%;padding:3px;position:relative;border-radius:10px;background:linear-gradient(to right, #44d9e6, #0978ef)">
  <div style="display: flex; background:#fff; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:#0978ef; margin-top: 23px;"></i>
    <div style="background:#fff;padding:1rem;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold"> Contáctanos a través de la vía correspondiente en caso de tener alguna duda, inconveniente o sugerencia.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Agregué 2 clases: Una `box` al `<div>` que encierra al ícono y al texto. Y otra `icon` al ícono.

Con [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS) y [`flex-direction: row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) (que no hace falta porque es el valor por defecto) hacés que los elementos "hijos" se coloquen en una fila. Con [`align-items: baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) hacés que tanto el ícono como el texto estén alienados.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.0/js/all.js"></script>

<div style="padding:3px;position:relative;border-radius:10px;background:linear-gradient(to right, #44d9e6, #0978ef)">
  <div class="box" style="background:#fff;padding:1rem;line-height:2em;font-weight:bold">
    <i class="icon fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:#0978ef"></i> Contáctanos a través de la vía correspondiente en caso de tener alguna duda, inconveniente o sugerencia.
  </div>
</div>
```